# How to update multiple rows with values of two arrays in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I need to update a set of records in the x table with values stored in arrays. Anyone know how I could do it?

```
IDS_NEW_SPONSORS INTEGER[] := ARRAY[]::INTEGER[]; --possible values [1,2,3,4,5,6]
IDS_DEBTORS  INTEGER[] := ARRAY[]::INTEGER[]; --possible values [20,21,22,23,24,25]
-- the arrays will be the same size--
UPDATE x
SET id_sponsor = [IDS_NEW_SPONSORS],-- HOW ADD
id_sponsor_historial = [IDS_DEBTORS], -- HOW ADD
id_patron = 5 -- ALWAYS SAME
WHERE id_sponsor = ANY(IDS_DEBTORS); -- this line working!!! loop each row
```

I'm working with postgres 11...

After update. the table would look like this:

```
id_sponsor | id_sponsor_historial | id_patron
1            20                     5
2            21                     5
3            22                     5
4            23                     5
5            24                     5
6            25                     5
```

Comment: Please provide your desired result. What values you want to be in `id_sponsor` & `id_sponsor_historial` fields after update?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I added the result of the table after the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next a little tricky query do this work:

(The trick is match value in new values array by position in old values array)

```
UPDATE sponsors
SET 
    id_sponsor_historial = id_sponsor, -- save previous value as historical
    id_sponsor = (array[1,2,3,4,5,6])[array_position(array[20,21,22,23,24,25], id_sponsor)],-- update new value
    id_patron = 5
WHERE id_sponsor = ANY(array[20,21,22,23,24,25]); -- find rows
```

I rest the integers array for example. In your case it should be changed to variables. The example works only if new and old values arrays have equals lengths.

Comment: @zannier, strange I tested the solution. Please look the fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1407e9c300cd3d7df81576be8ae740ac

Comment: A LOT OF THANKS.. It's rigth. Sorry I forgoten to put the correct values in ANY( array[])

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to do that. Here is an example:

```
create table x(
    id_sponsor int primary key,
    id_sponsor_historial int,
    id_patron int);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_x(
    integer,
    integer[],
    integer[])
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE

in_pat    ALIAS FOR $1;
in_sp_arr  ALIAS FOR $2;
in_sp_hi_arr ALIAS FOR $3;

BEGIN

IF in_sp_arr ISNULL 
THEN
RETURN 0;
END IF;

IF array_lower(in_sp_arr,1) ISNULL
   OR array_upper(in_sp_arr,1) ISNULL
THEN
RETURN 0;
END IF;

FOR index IN array_lower(in_sp_arr,1) .. array_upper(in_sp_arr,1) LOOP
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO x(id_sponsor, id_sponsor_historial, id_patron )
    VALUES ( in_sp_arr[index], in_sp_hi_arr[index], in_pat);
    --EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN    
    --do nothing ?
    END;
END LOOP;  
RETURN 1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;

select update_x(5, ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6],ARRAY[20,21,22,23,24,25]);
```

This would probably need more error checking: It assumes for example, that the arrays are of the same size, have the same bounds and all the elements are defined.

Comment: I'm going to try the solution

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to do is update the records as follows
A: Replacing the old sponsors (old_sponsor) with the new ones (new_sponsor)
B: Updating the historical_sponsor_id with the values ​​of old_sponsor
C: Adding all of them the same id_patron

I could do it this way based on the @clamp response..

```
DECLARE
   new_sponsor INTEGER[] := array[2300,2034,2032];
   old_sponsor INTEGER[] := array[1500,1501,1502];
BEGIN
   FOR i IN array_lower(new_sponsor, 1) .. array_upper(new_sponsor, 1)
   LOOP
    UPDATE x SET id_sponsor = new_sponsor[i],
        id_sponsor_historial = old_sponsor[i], id_patron = 5
    WHERE id_sponsor = old_sponsor[i];

   END LOOP;
END
```

I would like to know if it is useful for processing more than 10,000 records or if there is a better way to do it efficiently.

Comment: Please do not use an answer to modify your question. Edit the question or post a new one.

Comment: I would not try this with 10000 records. Why don't you do want to do the loop on the client side?

Comment: ok, Im new user in stackoverflow... Because I am trying to do everything in the database, but if it is not an optimal solution, I will do what it proposes. I don't have much knowledge about how to work with large volumes of data, that is, when they exceed 10,000 records or reach 100,000

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to achieve this would be using UNNEST:

```
UPDATE sponsors
SET
  -- save previous value as historical
  id_sponsor_historial = bulk_query.id_sponsor,
  -- update new value
  id_sponsor = bulk_query.updated_id_sponsor,
  -- set another field
  id_patron = 5
FROM
  (
    SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
      array[20,21,22,23,24,25]::INT[],
      array[1,2,3,4,5,6]:INT[]
    ) AS t(id_sponsor, updated_id_sponsor)
  ) AS bulk_query
WHERE
  sponsors.id_sponsor=bulk_query.id_sponsor
```

This effectively creates a temporary table from the two arrays, and then uses that to perform the update.

I've written more about using UNNEST with Postgres in this blog post: https://www.atdatabases.org/blog/2022/01/21/optimizing-postgres-using-unnest